# How to display the dot of a decimal based on the locale but without being in a decimal number?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a calculator-like with obviously number buttons and a `.` button.

How can I display it depending on the local used knowing it's in the end more like a string than a decimal, so I guess I cannot use NSNumberFormatter for that.

Is there a way to do it without "translating" it for every language that I will use (which will be way less than there are locales)?

I thought of creating a formatted number like `0.1` using the locale, format it into string and keep only the `.` it its locale version but I guess there are proper ways

Thanks

Comment: Gee, if only there were some object you could consult, like a locale, which had some attribute it would give you, like the decimal separator value.  Too bad that's not the case, eh?  (Because you would have seen it when you checked the documentation, right?)

Comment: Yes I would probably have seen it if only I knew where to look as when I was referring to a locale, I was talking about the `System locale` used automatically when using `.DecimalStyle` as the `numberStyle` of the `NSNumberFormatter`. So if you could please point me in the right direction (what object to look at) instead of being sarcastic I would appreciate. Thank you

Comment: ?! What are you saying, there is no mention of "right direction" anywhere apart in my previous comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way for it to work, I don't know if it's the best way...

```
let decimalSeparator = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleDecimalSeparator) as? String
```

Comment: In Swift 3 I use `let decimalSeparator = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator as String?` or `let decimalSeparator = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator! as String`